# How to fix ':integrationTest NO-SOURCE' when running Gradle integrationTest Task with Docker

Tags: java, docker, gradle, integration-testing

I have some integration tests written with Spring Boot and want to run them on demand. Not while doing **./gradlew build** but I want to run them with **./gradlew integrationTest**.

I want to run this **integrationTest** task inside Docker container

I have put the integration tests code in the folder **src/integrationtest** and created the **integration-test.gradle** file as below: [I'm using *Gradle 5.2*]

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        resources.srcDir file('src/integrationtest/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
    integrationTestAnnotationProcessor.extendsFrom testAnnotationProcessor
}

idea {
    module {
        testSourceDirs += sourceSets.integrationTest.java.srcDirs
        testResourceDirs += sourceSets.integrationTest.resources.srcDirs
        scopes.TEST.plus += [configurations.integrationTestCompile]
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs the integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    shouldRunAfter test
}

check.dependsOn -= integrationTest
```

And also applied this on my **build.gradle** `apply from: 'gradle/integration-test.gradle'`

I've created this docker file and named it **Dockerfile.it**:

```
FROM openjdk:8u191-jdk-alpine as build
ENV APP_WORKSPACE=/workspace/app/
WORKDIR $APP_WORKSPACE
COPY gradlew .
COPY gradle gradle
COPY build.gradle settings.gradle $APP_WORKSPACE
COPY lombok.config lombok.config
COPY src src
ENV GRADLE_OPTS -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="aws-access-key-id"
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="aws-secret-access-key"
ENV AWS_REGION="us-west-2"
ENTRYPOINT ["./gradlew", "integrationTest"]
```

When I run the command **./gradlew integrationTest** directly on my terminal in the project folder, everything works just fine, but when I build the Docker Image and run the Docker container from that image, the actual output is:

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2-bin.zip
....................................................................................................................................................................................
Unzipping /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.2-bin/2di47o96ob6dhysr22jutthm6/gradle-5.2-bin.zip to /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.2-bin/2di47o96ob6dhysr22jutthm6
Set executable permissions for: /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.2-bin/2di47o96ob6dhysr22jutthm6/gradle-5.2/bin/gradle
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :compileIntegrationTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processIntegrationTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :integrationTestClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :integrationTest NO-SOURCE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3m 54s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

These lines are my problem:

```
Task :compileIntegrationTestJava NO-SOURCE  
Task :processIntegrationTestResources NO-SOURCE  
Task :integrationTestClasses UP-TO-DATE  
Task :integrationTest NO-SOURCE
```

What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more investigation, I found that I did wrong one thing, and that was, the name of the source files folder, I named it **integrationtest** instead of **integrationTest** for that configuration in the *integration-test.gradle* file to work properly!

[image]

Comment: saved me a while of debugging there, +1!